# Getting value of a ForeignKey instead ID

Tags: django, django-views

I have to pass a ForeignKey object in a json response, im doing it like this:

```
 data = {}
 p = Bets.objects.create( bet_id=request.POST['team'],number=number)
 data['success'] = p
 return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type='application/json')
```

`bet_id` field is a ForeignKey and number is a CharField, if in `data['success']` I pass `p.number` i can pass it with no troubles, but when I pass `p.bet_id` I get the id of that ForeignKey, I need to get the value, I'm trying with lookup fields with `p.bet_id__name` but i get the following error:

> 'Bets' object has no attribute 'bet_id__name'

My models:

```
class Teams(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Bets(models.Model):
    bet = models.ForeignKey(Teams)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

how can I achieve get the value instead the id?

Comment: Please show your models code.

Comment: If you are getting an error on a line of code, you should at least *show that line*.

Comment: @Joseph Ok, I have added the models

@DanielRoseman line of the error is  `data['success'] = p`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use:

```
data['success'] = p.bet.name
```

Note that this will create a second SQL query against your db to load the Team object tied to `p.bet`. To save yourself a little bit of overhead, you can change this line:

```
Bets.objects.create( bet_id=request.POST['team'],number=number)
```

To this:

```
Bets.objects.create( bet_id=request.POST['team'],number=number).select_related('bet')
```

Comment: I tried that before, but im still getting the same error:

`'Bets' object has no attribute 'bet__name'`

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I was thinking in queryset syntax. I'll edit my answer, one second.